# How can I convert JSON to Protocol Buffers in JMeter?

Tags: json, jmeter, protocol-buffers, protobuf-java

I'm using JMeter(5.2.1) to test protocol buffer.
My boss want to send protobuf data to server in JMeter.

So, I keep searching on google, I can't found any related document, though.

There are similar ways to convert, but I don't have idea does it right.

1. Add "Protocol buffers plugin" on JMeter Plugins Manager --> Can't found any plugins.
2. Load ".jar" file when you use pre-processor with Java, Beanshell or Groovy.
3. Create own plugin

I think, second way is very reasonable.

If am I right, could you plz give me any ideas for get the body data on script langs?

Thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Obtain a [Java library for Protocol Buffers](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/tree/master/java) and drop it (including all dependencies) under [JMeter classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)
2. Add a relevant [JSR223 Element](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) to your Test Plan and develop the code in order to:

   - read the JSON data
   - convert it to the required [protocol format](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/javatutorial#the-protocol-buffer-api)
   - [write the message](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/javatutorial#writing-a-message) to .proto file
3. That's it, you should be able to send the generated .proto file now

References:

- [Groovy: Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/)
- [Using Google's Protocol Buffers With Java](https://dzone.com/articles/using-googles-protocol-buffers-with-java)